# Best known upper bound for $\sigma(n)$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

I was looking around on Wikipedia and OEIS and the best I could find relies on RH (Robin's Theorem or Lagrimas's Theorem). Are there any good known bounds that don't rely on RH?

Comment: If you meant the asymptotic estimate of $\sup_{n \le x} \sigma(n)$ its second order terms depends on the RH, but its first order term is obtained by the Mertens theorem or the PNT. If you meant the asymptotic estimate of $\sum_{n \le x}\sigma(n)$, its second order terms are related to the [Dirichlet's divisor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet.27s_divisor_problem).

Comment: @reuns  Robin also proved an unconditional bound on $\sigma(n).$ The criterion that is equivalent to RH  comes from erasing one term in that. I put this in an answer.

Comment: @WillJagy I meant sure and this estimate for $\sup_{n \le x} \sigma(n)$ follows easily when applying the PNT and the Mertens theorems to $\sigma(\prod_{p \le k} p)$

Comment: @reuns thanks. I just found a paper in English that has the unconditional result, http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1175789744   I have the 1984 Robin paper in French, got that through campus library reprint request.  I never learned any a.n.t., I just got interested in this Nicolas survey http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf   with superior highly composite and colossally abundant numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  Robin we have an unconditional result (1984) that says that for $n \geq 13,$ we have the bound
$$ \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} < \; e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{0.64821364942...}{\log \log n},$$ with the constant in the numerator giving equality for $n=12.$ Note
$$  e^\gamma  = 1.7810724179901979852365\ldots  $$

This is stated in [a paper in English by Briggs](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1175789744) as Theorem 1.1.

If you would like to experiment, the easiest sequence of numbers that still gives very large values (almost $1$) of $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n \; e^\gamma \; \log \log n}$ is 
$$ A_n = \operatorname{lcm} \{ 1,2,3,4,5, ..., n-1,n \},  $$
where $A_n \neq A_{n-1}$ only when $n$ is a prime or prime power. The very best values come from the sequence of Colossally Abundant numbers, but that is a more difficult computer program.

Let's see, the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to the statement that, for $n \geq 5041 = 1 + 7!,$ the number $0.64821364942...$ can be replaced by $0.$

Comment: In a few lines : $N_k = \prod_{p \le k} p$, $\frac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k} = \prod_{p \le k} (1+\frac{1}{p})$. The PNT gives $\sum_{p \le k} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log k+M+o(\frac{1}{\log^2 k})$ thus
$\log \frac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k} = \sum_{p \le k} \frac{1}{p}+\sum_{p \le k}\left(\log(1+\frac{1}{p})-\frac{1}{p}\right)$ $ = \log \log k+M+o(\frac{1}{\log^2 k})+C-\sum_{p > k} \left(\log(1+\frac{1}{p})-\frac{1}{p}\right) $
$ =  \log \log k+M+C+o(\frac{1}{\log^2 k})$
and hence $\frac{\sigma(N_k)}{N_k} = \exp(\log \log k+M+C+o(\frac{1}{\log^2 k})) = e^\gamma\log k (1+o(\frac{1}{\log^2 k}))$

Comment: Conclude by using the PNT again to replace $N_k$ by $e^k$